# Error with pcl_ros, in ros fuerte

Tags: pcl, ros-fuerte, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem with pcl_ros.the problem is when you compile pcl_ros. when rosmake is used gives the following error:

```
mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package pcl_ros
  [rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
  Failed to invoke /home/dava/local/DIR/ros-underlay-fuerte/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only pcl_ros
  CMake Error at /usr/lib/vtk-5.8/VTKTargets.cmake:16 (ADD_EXECUTABLE):
    Command add_executable() is not scriptable
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /usr/lib/vtk-5.8/VTKConfig.cmake:200 (INCLUDE)
    /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindVTK.cmake:73 (FIND_PACKAGE)
    /home/dava/local/src/ros-fuerte/pcl/pcl/vtk_include.cmake:1 (find_package)
  
  
  
  
  CMake Error at /home/dava/local/DIR/ros-underlay-fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'pcl_ros'.  Look
    above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the broken
    dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /home/dava/local/DIR/ros-underlay-fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:227 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:4 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

i try to install all dependency related with vtk, but doesn't work

Any reply will be appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49447/error-with-pcl_ros,-in-ros-fuerte/) by [Dava2788](https://answers.ros.org/users/3554/dava2788/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2012-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to installed this patch first:
perception_pcl-1.0.1-vtk5.8.patch

---

Originally posted by [Dava2788](https://answers.ros.org/users/3554/dava2788/) with karma: 60 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2013-06-04**:
Thanks this solves for perception_pcl 1.2.4, here is the direct link to the patch https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/attachment/ticket/5243/perception_pcl-1.0.1-vtk5.8.patch